# Drop NaN in a for loop for each column (Longstaff Schwartz Monte Carlo)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, montecarlo

I will try to explain my problem. So I have two DataFrames , Df1 and Df2.
Each of them has 3 columns and 4 rows.
I will solve a quadratic functions with np.polyfit.

```
M=3 

for t in range(M-1,0,-1):

  regs = np.polyfit(Df1[:,t],Df2[:,t+1],2)

  C = np.polyval(regs,Df1[:,t])
```

But I want to use only the values which are smaller than 1.1

```
 Df1[Df1 < 1.1]
```

Now I have something like that

```
   [1. , 1.09, 1.08, NaN]
   [1. , 1., 1.07, 1.04]
   [1. , NaN, 1.01, NaN]
   [1. , 0.78, NaN,0.95]
```

And my Df2 looks like

```
    [0.1 , 0., 0.08, 0.]
    [0.1 , 0.11, 0., 0.09]
    [0.1 , 0.33, 0.22, 0.]
    [0.1 , 0.09, 0.108, 0.]
```

So what I want to do is for each column from Df1, if Df1 has a NaN 
Then I don't want to calculate it.

Here is what I tried to explain:

```
  X =[1.08,1.07,1.01]
  Y =[0.,0.09,0]
```

Comment: You could merge onto your main df then drop nas, you'd be able to do your calculations row wise then, brief isn't 100% clear to me let me know if you want some sample code

Comment: Thank u :) . It would be good if u give me some sample code

Answer (score 0):

I tried this one

```
S = [[1.,1.09,1.08,1.34],[1.,1.16,1.26,1.54],[1.,1.22,1.07,1.03],[1.,0.93,0.97,0.92],[1.,1.11,1.56,1.52],
[1.,0.76,0.77,0.9],[1.,0.92,0.84,1.01],[1.,0.88,1.22,1.34]]

K= 1.1

Sn = np.asarray(S)

r = 0.06
T=1
M=3

dt = T/M
h= np.maximum(K-Sn,0)
V = np.copy(h)
disk = np.exp(-r*dt)


for i in range(M-1,0,-1):

   reg = np.polyfit(Sn[:,i],V[:,i+1]*disk,2)
   C = np.polyval(reg,Sn[:,i])

   V[:,i] = np.where(C > h[:,i],V[:,i+1]*disk,h[:,i])

C0 = disk* 1/8 * np.sum(V[:,1])
```

And my result for C0 is 0.11973..

This is the Longstaff Schwartz Monte Carlo Algorithm for pricing American Options.

But in the paper from Longstaff Schwartz ,they get a little different result

https://people.math.ethz.ch/~hjfurrer/teaching/LongstaffSchwartzAmericanOptionsLeastSquareMonteCarlo.pdf

(Page120)

They get 0.114. But I don't see my mistake